# changing password for schema user in flyway

Tags: oracle, maven, liquibase, flyway

I'm just getting started with flyway so this may be a nube question. What is the default password of the 'webapp' schema? And how do I change that?
This is what my pom.xml looks like. I have not pre-created the schema so flyway creates it on first build.

```
<username>system</username>
<password>manager</password>
<table>flyway_schema</table>
 <locations>
      <location>filesystem:src/sql</location>
 </locations>
 <schemas>
       <schema>webapp</schema>
  </schemas>
```

Comment: According to me, your database user should first  exists, otherwise how flyway get an access to database to create the schema? Thus first create the user on the database system, you can choose the password you want.

Comment: You need to have a user/password that is granted the priviledge of creating schemas. This is a pure database user, not related to flyway in any way.

Comment: Im on oracle so each schema managed by flyway is also a user. My question is how do I manage the password of the schema user created by flyway? In this case its the user 'webapp'  Note that the database does exist and flyway uses system/manager to log in but then creates the user 'webapp' and deploys the initial build. I have no idea what password it generates for the user webapp

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle the password is "flyway" for schemas created on migration. This is not currently possible to configure. See the source here: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/dbsupport/oracle/OracleSchema.java#L81